# Is it possible enter a running transaction using psql (the cli tool)?

Tags: postgresql, testing, transactions

I run tests with a debugger against the db using transactions.
Sometimes, when I hit a breakpoint, I would want to look around in the database using the same transaction my test currently is using, see what its code is seeing.
I know, I can access the db via the debugger, but some straightforward SQL sometimes would be less complicated.

Is this possible, somehow?

Comment: You could try [pg_dirtyread](https://github.com/df7cb/pg_dirtyread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reasonable wish, and it could be handy, but there is no way to do that in PostgreSQL.

Comment: That's what I was fearing...

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect `pg_stat_activity` table to see all queries currently being processed. With the right priviliges you can also list the contents of `pg_temp` schemas and see what temp objects are created as well as some of their metadata. You can let your code inject tags and other information into comments in your queries, by which you'll be able to link a query seen in `pg_stat_activity` to a particular worker process.

But you cannot hijack a session or inspect the contents of tables in `pg_temp` schemas belonging to other sessions, even with elevated privilages - I think it's a purposefully maintained technical limitation.

If you're using PL/pgSQL, you can modify your functions to save debugging information somewhere.
For test runs, you can also switch from `temp` tables to `unlogged` tables that will give you pretty much the same performance, but won't be deleted after the session ends. Keep in mind that it can cause conflicts: if two or more sessions used to operate each on its own `temp` table, after switching to `unlogged` they'll have to use different names or schemas.

Comment: All true, and there is also the shared lock table `pg_locks` and other things, but all that does not allow you to inspect the state of the database as seen by that transaction...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I agree, which is why I upvoted your answer. I started this as a comment but since it did not fit under the character limit, I figured I'll leave it as a backup answer for anyone looking for this, but also considering any method available to inspect queries at runtime, on the db.